# MUI Material UI React Hook useTheme() is legacy, what is the alternative?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, material-design

If the React Hook `useTheme()` is legacy, how can one access theme props outside of `JSX` and `CSS` and not by using `sx` prop?

For example, I have a more complex logic in a component and need to access my custom theme properties in some handlers, but I don’t want to use legacy APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `@mui/material`...

I believe it is only `@mui/styles` useTheme that is deprecated (per this page: https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/)

And so you should be able to use the `useTheme` hook from `@mui/material/styles` as shown here:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component

Here's another option I found:
https://mui.com/system/styled/#parameter-when-using-function-are-different-for-each-field
(allows for the theme to be used directly in the sx prop)